# Looking for a framework / pattern to deal with changes to a certain dataset

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, backend

I am writing the backend for a customer CMS and I am looking for a term / framework / pattern / mechanism for the following use case:

Let's say I have a Person in my database. Based on N third-party services, I get new data for this person (e.g. an address change). Now I am not allowed to apply the change from the 3rd party service to my Person dataset. Instead, I need to mark this Person somehow that there was an update found for that Person and a real person has to review this change before I can apply it to my Person object in the database.

So what I am looking for is a way to simplify this without creating a huge over-engineered change system in my database and backend. I thought I would need something like a versioning system for my database and for each change, I would create a new revision of that dataset and allow the real person to mark a certain revision as the "live" revision.

I hope my text makes sense and someone can help me out to at least allow me to google for the right term :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with the following columns:

`ID, Person, DateChange, Approved`

**ID** is auto-incremented primary key.

**Person** references the person table entry

**DateChange** is a date object with the date the person object was changed

**Approved** is a boolean value that determines if the change has been approved.

If you want to create a revision of each person (even if it already exists) you will have to create a new person entry and add it to this table.

Then have some queries that will get all the unapproved entries that someone can review and "approve it".

Once they are approved you can get all the "approved" entries from this table, sort by the date changed and get the first one for the newest person to display the information.